# How to render quicker a Symfony3 app on an VirtualBox Ubuntu VM hosted by Windows 10?

Tags: symfony, virtual-machine, virtualbox, share

So I have this web-app which is roughly like a complex Back-Office accessible through a sconnection with a login/password.

It's a Symfony3.0 application running with PHP5.6, MySQL and Apache 2.4.

In order to set up properly my dev environment, I've choosen to use a VirtualBox Virtual Machine to do the job as the web server. I access it from the host machine thanks to the Bridge Connection that makes the VM appear as another computer of my local aera network (`192.168.1.33`).

My problem is that I render the website (accessing `app_dev.php`) in **~7900ms** (to say the least).
This rendering is gotten from the Symfony web-toolbar at the bottom of the screen, that is to say the DOM rendering is not taken into account.

[image]

The VM has 8192Mo of RAM, shares a 12Go virtual disk-drive and has been provided with 4 cores of my processor.

So far, I tried:

- increasing the VM specifications to gain performances, to no avail;
- installed WAMP to gain several seconds to reach **~2500ms** (but I don't want to work with WAMP);
- installed Docker for Windows but Kaspersky, despite configurating it properly, won't let my drive been shared to Docker.

What could I do to render my website in, say, 3000 / 3500ms? Am I missing something obvious? Is what I'm asking even possible?

Feel free to ask any needed info!

Comment: does every request take same or similar amount of time? did production takes same time?

Comment: Hi @SamiulAminShanto, yes indeed, all others requests on this environment take the roughly same amount of time. And of course, the production renders much much quicker.

Comment: I can suggest two things. first, even symfony3 can run in php 5.6, upgrade it to 7.1 or higher and make sure OPcache is enabled.

Comment: Is your project in a shared directory?